# Translate Validation Messages in Silex

Tags: php, symfony, silex

Code:

```
   $app->register(new Silex\Provider\TranslationServiceProvider(), array(
      'locale' => 'sr_Latn',
      'translation.class_path' => __DIR__ . '/../vendor/symfony/src',
      'translator.messages' => array('sr_Latn' => __DIR__ .'/../vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/translations/validators.sr_Latn.xlf')
    ));
    $app['translator.loader'] = new Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\XliffFileLoader();
```

and I still get validation messages in english. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a call to `Translator::addResource`:

```
$file = __DIR__ .'/../vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/translations/validators.sr_Latn.xlf';
$app['translator']->addResource('xliff', $file, 'sr_Latn', 'validators');
```

See also `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection::registerTranslatorConfiguration`.

Comment: Thanks, it works only if I put `$app['translator']->addLoader('xlf', new Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\XliffFileLoader());` insted  `$app['translator.loader'] = new Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\XliffFileLoader();`. With `$app['translator.loader']` it throws `RuntimeException` with message `The "xlf" translation loader is not registered.`. And it's `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection\FrameworkExtension::registerTranslatorConfiguration` not `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection::registerTranslatorConfiguration`. Thanks a lot, this really helped.

Comment: Maybe doc http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/translation.html#yaml-based-language-files should be updated.

Comment: A pull request for a recipe would be awesome.

Comment: Cool, just please confirm that this is the right way to do it https://gist.github.com/1845379